Is there a way to always load all tabs inactive when you load chrome?
When you had a lot of tabs open last session it lags a lot to open chrome and you never want to use all tabs. So it would be good if you could just load chrome without all the tab processes active. You would just load all tabs like when you finalize their processes from the task manager.

It seems like an easy solution: configure Chrome not to load the last session; you, of course, won't be loading your last session. What exactly is your question?

Imagine I had 20 tabs, but now i load Chrome cause i want to use 1 of them; I want all to be inactive so I can just activate the tab i want to use (I don't want to lose the tabs i had opened).

Chrome, by default, will suspend unused tabs; there is no avoiding the initial hit if you want to load your previous session after closing the browser, though. Chrome can only suspend tabs after they are loaded. If you want different behavior other.  Chromium based browsers and Firefox all support suspending tabs in this way, but both engines will effectively require a performance hit if the session is restored.

Thank you for answering. Yea, that, I would like to load the browser with all tabs suspended. Do you know which chromium based browser can do that? I also use Brave, but i don't think it can.

Your question indicates you are using Chrome, not Brave. While Chromoim browser will mostly act the same, Brave, Google Chrome, and Edge, for instance, have different tab optimizations.
